# Rosen's uniqueness theorem for concave payoff functions and linear inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Can Rosen's existence and uniqueness of equilibrium theory be applied to a game with $n$ players with each player $i$ having the following payoff maximization model:

$$\max  f(x_i,x_{-i})$$
$$\text{s.t.}$$
$$x_i \le \bar{x}$$

where $f$ is a strictly concave function. And the constraints are decoupled. Each $x_i$ is smaller than the same scalar, $\bar{x}$.

Can I use Rosen's conditions to prove that there is a unique Nash equilibrium to this game? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By counter example, no.  Let's compactify strategy spaces by supposing for all $i$, $x_i \in [0, 1]$.  Suppose utilities are given by:
$$
f_i(x_i ,x_{-i}) = x_i\sqrt{x_{-i}} -\frac{x_i^2}{2}
$$
Then best replies are given by:
$$
x_i^*(x_{-i}) = \sqrt{x_{-i}}
$$
yielding pure strategy equilibria at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: This is a great example of why "diagonally strictly concave" payoffs is so much stronger than "strictly concave" payoffs.